# Element 'Listitem' is not a known element

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a Drop down field, however List Items seem to be ignored. This is for an aspx project I am working on in Visual studio. Am I missing something? My code:

```
<form runat="server">
  <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID ="dateField" runat="server" placeholder="Date (DD/MM/YYYY)"></asp:TextBox><br/>
   <asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="">   </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:ListItem Text="General Waste" Value="General Waste"></asp:ListItem>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have closed the `DropDownList` tag before the `ListItem`. `ListItem` should be IN the `DropDownList`.

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID ="dateField" runat="server" placeholder="Date (DD/MM/YYYY)"></asp:TextBox><br/>
    <asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="">   
        <asp:ListItem Text="General Waste" Value="General Waste"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</form>
```